# wxPython - PaintDC not refreshing

Tags: python, user-interface, graphics, wxpython

```
import wx

class TestDraw(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,id=-1):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent,id)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("#FFFFFF")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT,self.onPaint)
    def onPaint(self, event):
        event.Skip()

        dc=wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.BeginDrawing()
        width=dc.GetSize()[0]
        height=dc.GetSize()[1]
        if height<width:
            self.drawTestRects(dc)
        else:
            dc.Clear()
        dc.EndDrawing()

    def drawTestRects(self,dc):
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("#000000",style=wx.SOLID))
        dc.DrawRectangle(50,50,50,50)
        dc.DrawRectangle(100,100,100,100)

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(640,480))
        self.mainPanel=TestDraw(self,-1)

        self.Show(True)


app = wx.App(False)
frame = TestFrame(None,"Test App")
app.MainLoop()
```

This code should draw the test rectangles only when the height is less than the width, and otherwise the window should remain clear. However, if you mess with resizing the window, the panel isn't actually redrawn unless it is moved off the window. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a method to handle `wx.EVT_SIZE` or the panel and invalidate it there. Alternatively simply use the [`wx.FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html) for the panel.

Comment: On wx.EVT_SIZE handler, call `self.Refresh()`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for a [SizeEvent](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.SizeEvent-class.html) claims that there may be some complications when drawing depends on the dimensions of the window. I do not know exactly what is going on behind the scenes. I followed the suggestion on the link and added the call `self.Refresh()` to the top of `onPaint()` and this seems to give the desired behavior. See mghie's answer for a more efficient example of working code.

Comment: That way every paint action causes a new one. Do you get 100% processor load?

Comment: No I don't, but I shouldn't need to rethrow a paint event. :P (just read the doc for wx.Window.Refresh() and saw that it throws a paint event, too). I was more trying to point in the direction as to why it's happening.